# Button is clicked, next page displayed but

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have a submit button on a page, which allows a user to reset a password after entering their email. I can "successfully" click on the button using element.click(), element.submit() or using JS as per code below:

```
@FindBy(xpath = ("//button[contains(text(), 'Send new password')]"))
private WebElement setNewPasswordButton;

public forgotPasswordPage clickSetNewPasswordButton(WebDriver driver)
{
    //setNewPasswordButton.click();

    //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", setNewPasswordButton);

    setNewPasswordButton.submit();

    return this;
}
```

When the button is clicked in Selenium, I do see the next page which says "you should receive an email to reset your password". **However** I never receive the password reset email in my inbox.

When I run the process manually it works fine all the time i.e. an email is sent to my inbox for password reset.

**What I have noticed** is that when I click via Selenium (using any of the three methods above) it almost instantaneously flicks over to the "you should receive an email to reset your password" page. However when I run the test manually there is a noticeable delay of 1 - 2 seconds before the "you should receive an email ..." page is displayed. This suggests to me that the Selenium click is somehow not initiating the password reset functionality.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Adding HTML as requested:

```
<div id="root" style="height: 100%;"><div data-reactroot="" style="height: 100%;"><span class="redux-toastr" aria-live="assertive"><span><div class="top-left"></div><div class="top-right"></div><div class="top-center"></div><div class="bottom-left"></div><div class="bottom-right"></div><div class="bottom-center"></div></span></span><!-- react-empty: 322 --><form class=""><div class="sc-kNBZmU iUcwTp"><img src="/f5ef6979404e3773b6d263adea9c4b5b.png" alt="Test logo" class="sc-iCwjlJ bZQcHn"></div><div class="mt-10 container"><div class="row"><div class="col-8 offset-2 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4"><div class="sc-cHGsZl pt-5 pb-4 hMshLY"><h1 class="text-center">Forgot password</h1></div><p class="text-center">Enter your email address and your password will be reset and emailed to you.</p><div><div class="form-group"><!-- react-text: 457 --><!-- /react-text --><input name="email" value="bobTest123+547547@gmail.com" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="text"></div><div class="sc-eopZyb iZMZhY"><button type="submit" class="sc-bdVaJa fVCJpx btn btn-primary">Send new password</button></div></div></div></div></div></form><div class="sc-jxGEyO llyLPV container"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex mt-5"><div class="mr-3"><strong>Test-ui-v2: </strong><span>0.83.5</span></div><div class="mr-3"><strong>styleguide: </strong><span>0.16.3</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){
    var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];
    if(!analytics.initialize) {
      if(analytics.invoked) window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{
        analytics.invoked=!0;
        analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","page","once","off","on"];
        analytics.factory=function(t){
          return function(){
            var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            e.unshift(t);
            analytics.push(e);
            return analytics
          }
        };
        for(var t=0;t<analytics.methods.length;t++){
          var e=analytics.methods[t];
          analytics[e]=analytics.factory(e);
        }
        analytics.load=function(t){
          var e=document.createElement("script");
          e.type="text/javascript";
          e.async=!0;
          e.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";
          var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
          n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)};
          analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="3.1.0";
          analytics.load("lRqYQgiwd78XM7uLT8ECR3Cv4dPEDalH");
      }
    }
  }();
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Apologies for the formatting.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: try once with thread.sleep and then click

Comment: Can you share the URL , if it is public ?

Comment: The HTML You have provided is more of a JS involved in it.